# Setting up 'localhost' equivalent bindings with IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

I'm trying to define a binding on an Windows server 2008 IIS 7 machine to locally accept something like "mysite" as its address. "Localhost" is already defined to another website on the same machine.

My problem is that localhost works fine for that other website (as long as I keep the ip binding to "All Unassigned". However, no other binding works for this new site I'm trying to configure.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you testing it?

Are you typing http://mysite in your browser?

Did you put "mysite" in your HOSTS file and point it to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Hmmm, while you posed it as a question, it still contains the answer :P . Thank you, for some reason, I keep forgetting about the hosts file. I should take some b12 for my memory. thanks again.

Comment: I was actually *hoping* that was the answer ;-)